# retrieving encrypted data actual size

Tags: .net, encryption, padding

In .NET framework, I'm trying to encrypt some binary data (using RijndaelManaged), for decrypting I used the following sample code (C++/.NET):

```
RijndaelManaged^ rjdAlg= gcnew RijndaelManaged;
rjdAlg->IV= IV;
rjdAlg->Key=this->key;
ICryptoTransform^ decryptor= rjdAlg->CreateDecryptor();
MemoryStream^ msDecrypt = gcnew MemoryStream(encryptedData);
CryptoStream^ csDecrypt = gcnewCryptoStream(msDecrypt,decryptor,CryptoStreamMode::Read);
array<unsigned char>^ decryptedData= gcnew array<unsigned char>(encryptedData->Length);
csDecrypt->Read(decryptedData,0,decryptedData->Length);
```

Now, decryptedData contains useful data in addition to nulls (as the array initialization), how can I get the actual size of encrypted data ( if it was string I can just stop at the first null!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the length separately, either as the first N bits/bytes of your encrypted data, or outside of the encrypted data.

Rijndael is a block cipher, which means it will always encrypt whole blocks, and you always get whole blocks back when decrypting.

Comment: Thanks, but as I know the incomplete block will be padded (in my case with PKCS7 padding), this padding chars will be removed at decryption phase, I want to know if it is possible to know the size in the stream after decryption.

Comment: No, that's what I tried to say in my answer. If you want the exact length, you need to store it in addition to the data you encrypt. There's no other way.